# Inherited getter returns null

Tags: java, abstract-class

I have two classes for Chess, an abstract parent class `Piece` and its normal child class `Rook`.

```
public abstract class Piece {
    public enum Color {
        BLACK, WHITE;
    }

    public enum Name {
        KING, ROOK, BISHOP, QUEEN, KNIGHT, PAWN,
        FERZ, WAZIR
    }

    private Name name;
    private Color color;

    public Piece(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Name getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
```

-

```
public class Rook extends Piece {
    private Name name;
    private Color color;

    public Rook(Color color) {
        super(color);
        this.name = Name.ROOK;
    }
}
```

Then I use `Rook` in another class:

```
new Rook(Piece.Color.BLACK).getName() //null
new Rook(Piece.Color.BLACK).getColor() //BLACK
```

Why does `getName()` return `null`?

Comment: because you can´t override variables, you can just hide them. The method  `getName` in the scope of the class `Piece` has no clue about the variable `name` in the class `Rock`. And since you never set `name` in `Piece` you are getting the null value.

Comment: add a `protected` `setName` method in `Piece`, remove the name field from `Rook`, and maybe also add a `Piece` constructor that lets you set the name directly (and the color). also as a general hint: either use sub-classes of Piece, or use the enum, but to use both, and have a 1-to-1 relationship makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you effectively have two fields in Rook called "name" - one inherited from Piece and one directly in Rook (they're both private so there is no name conflict, since you can't see Piece.name from Rook). In Rook constructor, you're assigning to Rook.name, but in getName() you're reading from Piece.name.

What you need to do is:

- delete "name" field from Rook
- add "Name name" parameter to Piece constructor
- modify Rook constructor to call super(color, Name.ROOK)

Comment: Should I delete the `color` field from Rook as well?  It would be useless since I'm using the one from `Piece`.

Comment: Yes, `color` should be removed as well.

Answer (score 4):

You have two fields called `name`: the one in the subclass is **hiding** the one in the parent abstract class. the constructor of `Rook` initializes the `name` of `Rook`. However, the inherited `getName()` returns the value of `name` in `Piece`. If you remove the one in the subclass, it will print a non-null value (you will have to change the modifier to `protected` however):

```
public abstract class Piece {
   ...

   protected Name name;
   protected Color color;

   ...
}
```